# Google static maps - group some points with custom marker

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm using google static [maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/)

I'm trying to display 2 groups (with option for more) of geo points.
Each group has different icon.

this url displays only the center icon with out others

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap
?center=31.909440199627042,35.00186054020873
&zoom=14
&size=1200x1200
&markers=icon:http%3A%2F%2Ftinyurl.com%2F2ftvtt6|31.909440199627042,35.00186054020873|31.909440199627042,35.00186054020873
&markers=icon:http%3A%2F%2Ftinyurl.com%2F2ftvtt6|31.909440199627042,35.00186054020873|31.909440199627042,35.00186054020873&sensor=false
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your request:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap
?center=31.909440199627042,35.00186054020873
&zoom=14
&size=1200x1200
&markers=icon:http%3A%2F%2Ftinyurl.com%2F2ftvtt6|31.909440199627042,35.00186054020873|31.909440199627042,35.00186054020873
&markers=icon:http%3A%2F%2Ftinyurl.com%2F2ftvtt6|31.909440199627042,35.00186054020873|31.909440199627042,35.00186054020873&sensor=false
```

First: why do you have 2 `markers` fields?

Then: your markers are at exactly the same locations... So you see only 1 pin.

If I try the following (removed the 2nd markers and changed a value) I see 2 pins:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap
?center=31.909440199627042,35.00186054020873
&zoom=14
&size=1200x1200
&markers=icon:http%3A%2F%2Ftinyurl.com%2F2ftvtt6|31.909440199627042,35.00186054020873|31.909440199627042,35.0000
&sensor=false
```

Comment: I know, thanks to your answer I found the real proplem.